# Is there a way to set the theme for Cairo-Dock to be the same as the Dash theme?

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, themes, cairo-dock

I have the Paper theme for Ubuntu and I would like Cairo-Dock's theme to be the same. However, I'm not sure how to get them to match other than finding Paper's directory of icons and setting each launcher to have the specific icon that Paper uses. Is this the only way or is there a better one?

Comment: haha you're welcome, it's normal

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was looking under `themes` for *different* themes but the default theme automatically matches the Dash theme.